# Speed/pace calculation code; keep getting invalid syntax. Very new; what am I doing wrong?

Tags: syntax

```
def calculation(minutes, seconds, miles):
    pace = (int(minutes) + (int(seconds)/60)/miles)
    speed = (float(miles)/(int(minutes) + (int(seconds)/60)
minutes = raw_input("Minutes ==> ")
seconds = raw_input("Seconds ==> ")
miles = raw_input("Miles ==>" )
```

I'm attempting to do an input that is supposed to calculate the pace and speed of user-inputted variables but I keep getting syntax errors starting from the fourth line down. I'm very new to this for the record so it's probably something stupid but any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please specify the language you're coding in (e.g. in heading or tags), especially if you're asking for help on syntax errors. Is it Python?

Comment: @User42 - please don't suggest putting them in the heading. See the meta question [Should questions include tags in their titles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles) to which the answer is, no, they should not.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever thanks for the hint, I agree with that. I just wanted to make sure it can be seen somewhere. Of course, tag is by far the better way to go!